# Permission Denied Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which will move and rename folders. It is successful when running it locally but when attempting to read or write to directories using mapped drives the process fails with a "Permission Denied" error.

Does VBScript not like mapped drives?  Below is the script with credentials to read and write to source and destination:

```
dim objNetwork

Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strLocalDrive = "Y:"
strRemoteShare = "\\servername\directory"
strPer = "False"
strUsr = "userid"
strPas = "password"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strLocalDrive, strRemoteShare, strPer, strUsr, strPas

Dim fso, objFol, objMoveFol, strPathBuild

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFol = fso.GetFolder("D:\Source")

For Each objMoveFol In objFol.SubFolders

    'Replace the root folder locations in the path
    strPathBuild = Replace(objMoveFol, "D:\Source", "Y:\Destination")

    'Do the required other fiddle
    strPathBuild = Replace(strPathBuild, "A.", "Ack~")

    fso.Movefolder objMoveFol, strPathBuild

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. Also if it is working locally I would guess that the user you are mapping the network drive with does not have permission to edit the folder.

Try mapping the drive manually with the same username and password. Copy a folder to the same location to check the users permissions

Comment: Bear Box, thanks for the response. I did follow through with your instructions and was able to manually map a drive to the destination and create a folder. I am not sure why I am getting this error but I do agree and believe the account being used may not have the right permission rights to navigate across the network. I will work with the network admin to see if we can make the account a domain admin just to test this process.  Thanks again for your feedback.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Bear Box, the network admin figured out the problem and we can move forward.  Properties for the VBS must change to include user account which will execute the process. Thanks for the feedback.